# Comparing between dates of two columns in different files (CSV, Excel) Java Apache commons and poi to know where the dates are similar

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi, apache-commons

I have an Excel and a CSV File. The two files contain dates in their first columns.

I want to compare these dates and look where are they the same, like to get true in the big excel file. But I am having problems with the date format difference between the two files.

I simply want java to know where these dates are similar, so i can update later on the excel file with values from the exported CSV File.

Link to the two files:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AphATk_r_LQkl0HBC2r_9nt_AYIg

My Code yet:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CsvToExcelConverter {

    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "C:/Users/blawand/Desktop/CSV_to_Excel/export-excel-test.xlsx";
    public static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "C:/Users/blawand/Desktop/CSV_to_Excel/export-csv-test.csv";
    public static List<String> dates_csv = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> dates_excel = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);) {

            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                // Accessing Values by Column Index
                String name = csvRecord.get(0);
                dates_csv.add(name);
            }

            dates_csv.remove(0);
        }

        FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        /*
         * ================================================================== 
         * Iterating
         * over all the rows and columns in a Sheet (Multiple ways)
         * ==================================================================
         */

        // Getting the Sheet at index zero
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if (row != null) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(0); // getColumn(0)
                if (cell != null) {
                    // Found column and there is value in the cell.
                    // String cellValueMaybeNull = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    String cellValueMaybeNull = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

                    // String to number set
                    dates_excel.add(cellValueMaybeNull);

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(dates_csv);
        System.out.println(dates_csv.size());
        System.out.println(dates_excel);
        System.out.println(dates_excel.size());

        while (dates_excel == dates_excel) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        }

        fsIP.close();
        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
        workbook.write(output_file);
        output_file.close();

    }
}
```

What would you like to know more? please ask me!
I would be very thankful

Comment: What do you mean by *dates are similar*? Don't you mean *equal*, like same day of year, same month of year and same year?

Comment: when it is the same day of the year. In the csv file it is written like 01.01.2018 but in the excel it is Mo 01/01/18 Thank you

Comment: Are those formats fixed? I mean will the dates in those files always be formatted as shown?

Comment: Yes the formats will stay fixed

Comment: Apache POI will give you back the dates as a Java `Date` object if you ask it. Why not format that to what your CSV uses before comparing?

Comment: How can I format that to the CSV file?

Comment: That depends on the one writing the csv file. If it is you, then you'll have to decide what to do: Re-format when csv is written or check different formattings in java.

Comment: I am not the one writing the csv file :(

Comment: hab eben gelesen, dass du aus Osnabrück kommst :)

Comment: Yes, I am German, too. But this is an English community, so let's stick to English because other readers might not be able to understand German. See my answer to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing dates for equality may be done by re-formatting and comparing the `String`s themselves or parsing those `String`s to `LocalDate`s and comparing those.

First option would be re-formatting one `String` to make it have the same formatting as the other one, but both stay `String`s.

The second possibility is creating a modern time representation out of both and compare them by the built-in comparison of this representation.

```
public class TryOutClass {

    /**
     * Compares two dates and checks if they are equal using {@link String} comparison.
     * <p>
     * <strong>Important note:</strong><br>
     * This assumes the first date given is of the format "EEE, dd/MM/yy" and 
     * the second one is of the format "dd.MM.yyyy".
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param dateOne the first date to be compared to the second
     * @param dateTwo the second date to be compared to the first
     * @return <code>true</code> if the dates are equal, otherwise <code>false</code>
     */
    public static boolean datesEqual(String dateOne, String dateTwo) {
        // cut off the leading weekday abbreviation
        String processedDateOne = dateOne.substring(4, 12);

        // split the String by its delimiter (/)
        String[] temp = processedDateOne.split("/");

        // concatenate the parts to fit the format of the second date
        String comparableDateOne = temp[0] + "." + temp[1] + ".20" + temp[2];

        // return the result of the String comparison
        return comparableDateOne.equals(dateTwo);
    }

    /**
     * Compares two dates and checks if they are equal using the comparison of {@link LocalDate}.
     * <p>
     * <strong>Important note:</strong><br>
     * This assumes the first date given is of the format "EEE, dd/MM/yy" and 
     * the second one is of the format "dd.MM.yyyy".
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param dateOne the first date to be compared to the second
     * @param dateTwo the second date to be compared to the first
     * @return <code>true</code> if the dates are equal, otherwise <code>false</code>
     */
    public static boolean equalDates(String dateOne, String dateTwo) {
        // define two formattings
        DateTimeFormatter firstFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy");
        DateTimeFormatter secondFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

        // create two LocalDates, the first one still needs to have the weekday abbreviation cut off
        LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(dateOne.substring(4, 12), firstFormatter);
        LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.parse(dateTwo, secondFormatter);

        // return the result of the LocalDate comparison
        return firstDate.equals(secondDate);
    }

    /**
     * The main method that just executes both possibilities 
     * of comparing differently formatted date {@link String}s
     * @param args (unused) command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateOne = "Wed 01/08/18";
        String dateTwo = "01.08.2018";

        System.out.println("#### datesEqual ####");
        String datesEqual = datesEqual(dateOne, dateTwo) ?
                "The dates are equal" : "The dates differ";
        System.out.println(datesEqual);

        System.out.println("#### equalDates ####");
        String equalDates = equalDates(dateOne, dateTwo) ?
                "The dates are equal" : "The dates differ";
        System.out.println(equalDates);
    }
}
```

> Please read all the comments in the code as they are the explanation of what the code does.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I still have one more step for my code based on your solution, is it okay to ask you one more time?

Comment: Ask here if it is related to date comparison, otherwise please post a new question.

Comment: can i link you then to the new quetion? But it is related to date comparison

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254215/updating-excel-sheet-values-based-on-a-csv-sheet-with-apache-poi

Comment: The link to the question asked by my colleage

Comment: Interesting... different account asking ;-) Colleague, ah... Same code?
I will have a look at it.

Comment: We are working on the same code :D We are still new to java

Comment: Thanks for your help!